# ExtJS Classic 7.3.0: Styling application views with .scss files

Tags: css, extjs, sass, sencha-architect

From [this link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html) for theming:

> To write CSS rules associated with an application view, you create an .scss file
> in the same folder and with the same base name as the view. For
> example, to style the view App.view.main.Main, you may can add Main.scss to that folder:

Following this, I have a 2 files in the same folder: Form.js and Form.scss

In Form.scss, if I define a custom class and include that in Form.js, it works and I see the style applies. This works:

```
.toolbar-red {
    background:green;
}
```

But if I do anything to reference an internal class for Extjs, it will not work. For example, this doesn't work:

```
.bold-grid .x-column-header-text-inner {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I know that this above style works, because when I add this style in my /theme/sass/src/Application.scss, it works as I want. FYI, I am using Sencha Architect, and adding my custom styles to the theme sass file works. But I want them to be in their separate file, and hence I am trying to add them to Form.scss. But as explained above, if I use an internal class, it won't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a different prefix for your own theme?

Maybe try this:

```
.bold-grid .#{$prefix}column-header-text-inner {
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to Sencha Themer?  If so its really easy to do.  Open up your theme in themer and create a custom UI for the toolbar.  You can do this for any component, BTW.  Whatever you name the custom UI is what you would use later in SA.
After it is saved and applied to your SA theme, go back into SA and recompile theme.  This is done by clicking button at very bottom of project inspector pane.  Once it is complete go to toolbar in project inspector and set ui config option to what you named custom ui.